# SQL DESC read from buttom

Tags: sql, arrays, fetch, reverse

This is my SQL Fetch Array:

```
SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%d.%m.%Y') AS datum, zu, ab
                        FROM BuchungenHeader 
                        WHERE id = '".$var_id."'
                        ORDER BY datum DESC
```

```
Date       | In | Out | Balance
15.11.2013 | 0  | 1   | 1 //(-0+1=1)
14.11.2013 | 2  | 4   | 3 //(-2+4+1=3) +1 is from above
13.11.2013 | 3  | 2   | 2 //(-3+2+3=2) +1 is from above
```

Is it possible to reverse that?

```
15.11.2013|0|1|2 //(-0+1+1=2) +1 from below
14.11.2013|2|4|1 //(-2+4-1=1) -1 from below
13.11.2013|3|2|-1 //(-3+2=1)
```

I don't want to use ASC, because I want to start with the last date.

Comment: could you please provide some information about your calculated column? You dont select "Balance" in your query, so i assume u calculate it by iterating over the resultset, and it is up to you in which direction you iterate it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Should be quite simple by a using the window function `lag()`